# Did I prove this statistics question correctly?

Tags: statistics

The question is  `Suppose A and B are two independent and disjoint events. Suppose P{B} = 1/2.  What is P{A}? Prove your answer`

My attempted solution:

Since they are independent then P{AB} = P{A}P{B},
Now since they are also disjoint we must satisfy the condition P{AB} = 0, so therefore P{A} must be 0 in order for the rules to hold for both independent and disjoint events.

I don't like that I got 0 is this correct?

Comment: The conclusion and method are correct.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Thank you I thought it was strange that the probability was zero.

Comment: Independence and disjointness are "almost" incompatible.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Ahh I didn't think about that. Thank you!